# perl Template: apply a regexp to a variable in a .tt2 file

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, openbsd

I absolutely don't speak any `perl` or [`perl` `Template`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/)!

I have a `perl` file with `use Template;` and a call to `->process` to process a `.tt2` file.  Within the `.tt2` file, a variable is printed, like so: `[% path | html %]`.

How do I apply an `s/,-.*//` (remove `,-` and what follows) to `[% path | html %]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars have a [`.remove` vmethod](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#method_remove).

```
[% path.remove(',-.*') | html %]
```

Comment: It works, thanks!  I've just noticed that I need to do this three times (e.g. I'd need `[% path.remove(',-.*') | html %]` repeated on 3 adjacent lines, and `path` is not used anymore afterwards in this `.tt2` file), any suggestion of whether such code could be made more succinct?

Comment: you can reassign `path` before the existing code: `[% path = path.remove(...) %]`